# Как унаследовать права из младшей группы?

Tags: c#

Есть H-ное количество словарей с листом внутри со списком прав.Возможно ли указать например для 3 словаря чтобы он унаследовал права 1 и 2 без перебора этих словарей на предмет нужного права?

```
{
  "Default": {
    "Default": true,
    "Commands": [
       "Test1"
    ]
  },
  "Vip": {
    "Default": true,
    "Commands": [
       "Test2"
    ]
  },
  "Admins": {
    "Default": true,
    "Commands": [
       "Test3"
    ]
  },
  "FullAdmins": {
    "Default": true,
    "Commands": [
       "Test4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

Создал бы перечисление

```
[Flags]
   enum Rights
    {
        Default = 0x000001,
        Vip= 0x000002| Default,
        Admins= 0x000004 | Vip,
        FullAdmins= 0x000008 | Admins
    }
```

В вашем классе, вместо списка имел бы данный битовый флаг.

Далее вы хитрым образом его инициализируете.

И можете использовать вот так:

```
    var testRights = Rights.FullAdmins;

    Console.WriteLine(testRights );
    Console.WriteLine($"Имеет права VIP? {testRights.HasFlag(Rights.Vip)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Имеет права Admins{testRights.HasFlag(Rights.Admins)}");
testRights = Rights.Default;
    Console.WriteLine(testRights );
    Console.WriteLine($"Имеет права VIP? {testRights.HasFlag(Rights.Vip)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Имеет права Admins? {testRights.HasFlag(Rights.Admins)}");
```

Вроде, работает, как вы хотели, так как мы избавились от перебора списков в классах и вышестоящие роли наследуют права нижестоящих.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @luxa1810 поправил вопрос - можете выложить пример с конструктором?Например чтобы у Admins был доступ к Test1 без указания как такового - унаследовал

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы привели пример такого словаря с доступными правами? Каждое нижелижащее право обладает правами предыдущего? Если да, то вам бы подошла бы реализация через перечисление с атрибутом [Flags]

Comment: да не обладает - мне и нужно чтобы например Admins имел право не только к своему Test3,но и к Test2 и Test1,но не имел к Test4.

Comment: получаю Method not found: 'System.Enum.HasFlag" - может из за net framework 3.5?

Comment: Версия фреймворка какая?

Comment: net framework 3.5?

Comment: Если верить MSDN, то этот метод появился только с версии 4,0. Альтернатива- это написать собственный метод https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set

Comment: @iluxa1810 в вашем примере `Default` будет 0, остальные все 1

Comment: @tym32167, пардон, забыл про индексацию с 0. Поправил.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы не делаете инкремента совсем. Теперь `defalut` =1, остальные = 3

Comment: @iluxa1810 если мне начать использовать  
net framework выше 3.5 то начинаются уже траблы на стороне движка https://b.radikal.ru/b17/1801/d1/9376cf1355c2.png

Comment: @tym32167, подправил.

Comment: @Сергей, вы можете написать собственный метод, который делает точно так же.

Comment: есть минус у данного подхода - если операций будет много то они могут не влезть даже в enum long. но если операций строго фиксированное количество, расширений программы не планируется то почему бы и нет. (+)

Comment: @iluxa1810 не могу - не настолько знаю C#.Но все равно спасибо

Comment: @iluxa1810 зачем вообще делать это? `0x000002| Default`, в чем смысл складывать? Не лучше ли тогда сами права делать типа `var test1 = Rights.Default | Rights.Admin`?

Comment: @tym32167, ну это уже тонкости реализации... Я лишь показал, что через битовые флаги можно добиться необходимой функциональности.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин количество операций тут без разницы, имеет значение только количество ролей

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть данные

```
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> rights = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>()
{
    {"Default", new HashSet<string>(){"Test1"}},
    {"Vip", new HashSet<string>(){"Test2"}},
    {"Admins", new HashSet<string>(){"Test3"}},
    {"FullAdmins", new HashSet<string>(){"Test4"}},
};

string[] groups = new[] { "Default", "Vip", "Admins", "FullAdmins" };
```

Тогда с перебором групп будет все просто

```
bool HasRight(string groupName, string rightName)
{
    var ind = Array.IndexOf(groups, groupName);
    if (ind < 0) return false;

    for(int i = ind; i>=0; i--)
        if (rights[groups[i]].Contains(rightName)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Проверить оч просто

```
Console.WriteLine(HasRight("Admins", "Test1")); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight("Admins", "Test2")); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight("Admins", "Test3")); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight("Admins", "Test4")); // false
```

Но есть вам надо без перебора всех элементов, то на основе существующего словаря можно собрать новый

```
var rights2 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
{
    rights2.Add(groups[i], new HashSet<string>());      
    for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        foreach(var right in rights[groups[j]])
            rights2[groups[i]].Add(right);
    }
}
```

Тогда проверка прав будет выглядеть еще проще

```
bool HasRight2(string groupName, string rightName, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> rights2)
{
    if (!rights2.ContainsKey(groupName)) return false;
    return rights2[groupName].Contains(rightName);
}
```

Тест:

```
Console.WriteLine(HasRight2("Admins", "Test1", rights2)); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight2("Admins", "Test2", rights2)); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight2("Admins", "Test3", rights2)); // true
Console.WriteLine(HasRight2("Admins", "Test4", rights2)); // false
```

Но вообще я бы не рекомендовал собирать новые словари, так как при изменении исходного словаря производный надо будет пересобирать.